# Why does creating a Drawable from an InputStream cause an OutOfMemoryError when the InputStream comes from a url but not from a asset?

Tags: android, png, out-of-memory

I am working on an app that displays floor plans for buildings. The floor plans are .png files hosted on a server.

This code causes an OutOfMemoryError:

```
InputStream is = null;
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://server/image.png");
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
is = response.getEntity().getContent();

Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, null); //this line causes an OutOfMemoryException

imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
```

But this code does not:

```
InputStream is = assetManager.open("image.png");
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, null);
imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
```

The images are fairly large in dimension (5100 x 3300 for one example) but that image is only ~100 KB viewing it online, and it's not much smaller (~95 KB) when looking at it in the .apk file.

Does anyone know why the first code snippet causes the error but the second one doesn't? During debugging the first InputStream is only ~102000 bytes in size and the second InputStream is only ~95000 bytes in size. That doesn't seem like a big enough size difference to explain the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drawable stream is going to create a bitmap drawable for it.  That means it needs to store the uncompressed full bitmap in memory. To do that, it needs to allocate the entire memory-  5100*3300*4 bytes, or 64 MB.  That's way way too large for Android.

When going from assets, it probably isn't reading the file until it has to, and isn't creating an in memory bitmap.  It can just keep the file pointer in memory.  But you can't do that with a stream, the stream may not be value by the time you get around to reading it, and you can't read it more than once (while you can a file).

Comment: +1. Definitely way too large for most Android devices, whether loading from the internet, resources, or elsewhere.